# strange texturing artefacts

Tags: texturing, lighting, procedural, artifacts

I made myself a procedural brushed metal texture. I use it to render CAD designed parts in blender. On most of the parts the texture looks great. But sometimes there are strange artefacts in the lightnig, as if the faces are not planar.
I've tried to retopoligize the mesh a bit, but somewhere, there are always this artefacts. The strange thing is, I symmetrized the mesh, and the mirrored faces look just fine.

Has someone a clue, what this could be?

[image: retopoligized side with artefacts]
[image: mirrored side]

Answer (score 0):

Somehow flipping the normals solved the problem, But why?

edit: not really, only in edit mode it looks ok then. Outside it looks strange again.
The tile at the left side has normal like other co-planar faces. Rest of the row has normals flipped inside.

edit2: i found out, that it has something to do with the origin of the object. when i move the origin outside the object, the artifacts dissapear...

[image: flipped normals]
[image: outOfEditMode]